# Electronic invoicing for designers?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, software-recommendation, resource-recommendations

I am wondering what you guys have a solution for invoice design?

For instance I have designed a nice invoice in AI and it seems like software like Xero does not accept SVG logos and you can't use a template backdop with background. So images we spend of time get rasterised.

Since most invoices are sent electronically these days a printed one from printers isnt an option.

I made it in PDF for the meantime but for long term it isnt an option due to the amount of invoices needing to be done.

Answer (score 1):

I have a template in InDesign which i use to generate PDF invoices, which i then send by email and print for accounting. Many clients are repeating jobs so i will just re-use older invoices and change the date and amount to be paid.

InDesign's master page feature makes it easy to lock your details in place and only edit the client and project info. Then you can organize invoices as separate files or into a single yearly multipage invoice book.

Another option is Google Docs with plenty of ready-made templates you can easily customize into invoice templates.

Then there are many Saas products like the Xero you mentioned or [Quickbooks](https://quickbooks.intuit.com/).